# MediaPlayer Service Android

Tags: android, android-service, android-mediaplayer

I am new to Android. I am creating service for Media Player so that it can continue to play song even if i close the application. I have created activity for Media Player and it is having all the functionality like play , pause , next , previous , seekbar and also includes oncompletionlistener . All works excellent. But Now i want that all should be managed by service.

I have Created MyService Class :

```
public class MyService extends Service {

    public static MediaPlayer mp;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        mp = new MediaPlayer();     
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {  
        return START_STICKY;
    }
```

But in my player activity i have created ArrayList for Songlist from which i am taking currentsongIndex and through it i am maintaining all the functionality like next , previous and all.. Now in service how do i get songlist which is also required in my activity ?? Where should i create MediaPlayer object mean in service or activity ??

for MediaPlayer I have reffered http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-building-audio-player-tutorial/ . For my media player code you can refer this site. Thanks.
Pleaze clear my doubt. I am so confused. Reply me soon..

Comment: Create it in service. That is the class that needs the song list.

Comment: Means i need to create songlist in service. But when i click on next button in activity how my service is going to handle ?

Comment: can you post the activity code too? Plus, i am not sure i am getting your requirement right. You can as well create a separate class for songs and then just call it using an object wherever required.

Comment: i have used media player code from the site which i mentioned above.

Comment: and i want service for playing song in background with this code.

Comment: Means activity code and service code are going to run in separately. Means just i need to implement code to play current song and to play next song in service ?? So that song continues to play.. Am i correct ??

Comment: Yes. You need to start the startservice method in the activity. You need to create the media player functionality in the service class.

Comment: @RahulBisht the file is not available on that link. Can u please upload the file link?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are on the right track.  I have adapted from the SDK Samples; this is how I do it and it works great.
From your ArrayList (in your activity NOT from the Service) call

```
onListItemClick
```

and start an intent that starts the music service:

```
startService(new Intent(MusicService.ACTION_PLAY));
```

In your manifest you will need to add:

```
 <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.blah.blah.action.PLAY" />
           <xxx xxx> 
 </intent-filter>
```

And of course in your Music Service you need to receive the Intent:

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    String action = intent.getAction();
    if (action.equals(ACTION_PLAY))
        processPlayRequest();
  }
```

Be sure to add Intents for skip, rewind, stop etc.
Let me know if this helps.

Comment: yes.. i want this only. but hw can i access activity button from my service as i want to change button sourceimage when i play and when i pause on same button. ne idea ??

Comment: That should probably be handled from within your Activity, but you could also initialize the Button like `public static Button myButton;` then you can change the image from anywhere, but I wouldn't recommend doing it this way...rather from within the `onClick` event and just let the Music Service handle the playback of the music. If you are happy with my answer above please mark as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

Getting the app to run in background should be taken care of by the 'Service' itself.
Try following this example http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html
A service is designed to work in the background.

Comment: sure. Try not to stick to one piece of code even while consulting tutorials. All you need to do is create the basic layout in the activity(buttons and some functions,etc). You can start the service in the 'onclick' of some button and let the service run in the background. the mediaplayer/songs go in the service class.

Answer (score 0):

I went through exactly the same thing!  It's a long haul to develop even a really great mp3 player app.  The answer is long.

Here are a few resources that really helped me. Android has a article on this very thing in their developer docs:

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Pay attention to what it says at the bottom of this long article about bound services and running in the foreground.

Additionally, managing player state is what caused me the most headaches.

You'll also want to take a look at threading because spawning that new service will still execute everything on the Main UI Thread, sounds crazy but true.   Take a look at the ExecutorService for managing thread pools.  I wish I could tell you it was easier.

Unfortunately most of my formal training from all over the web but with android services comes from a paid site:

http://www.pluralsight.com/training/Courses/TableOfContents/android-services

It is a good resource for all programmers I think but has great sections about many aspects of android programming that are only covered briefly at other tutorial sites.

The resources at Vogella are good also, mentioned above.